# The book about integration Django and Flex

Tags: python, django, apache-flex

There is a remarkable book "Flexible Rails" http://www.manning.com/armstrong/ about how to use Ruby on Rails and Adobe Flex to build next-generation rich Internet applications (RIAs). Does anybody know any similar resource about integrating Django and Flex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any similar books, but all you really need is an API integration from your flex app to your django app.

I've used the following 2 methods with success:

- REST API with simple HTTP access on the flex side.  See [django-piston](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/) and flex's mx.rpc.http.HTTPService/built-in XML deserializer.
- AMF protocol: See [django-amf-gateway](http://bitbucket.org/wolever/django-amf-gateway/) w/ [pyamf](http://pyamf.org/) for examples.